# Curved Borders for dynamic free flow tables in altova stylevision or xsl-fo without using the border-radius property

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop, altova

Iam new to Altova Stylevision and xsl-fo . I need to have curved borders for tables which are dynamic and flow across multiple pages. The border-radius property is not working as the property is neither recognized at table level nor row level nor cell level  by xsl-fo processor.I could not give the exact exception thrown when using the border-radius property as I have completed using the trail version.

Please find the details below:

```
<fo:root xmlns:altova="http://www.altova.com" 
         xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
         xmlns:fox="http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions">
```

I have used the fop extension from trunk and included the above line at the top of the XML.

Below is piece of my code which i have used to create curved border for cell.

```
<fo:table-cell visibility="hidden" padding="0" display-align="center"> 
  <fo:block-container overflow="hidden"> 
   <fo:block text-align="center" fox:border-before-radius-start="7mm" 
             fox:border-start-radius-before="7mm"> 
     <fo:inline font-family="RonBscRg" font-size="7pt">ee</fo:inline> 
   </fo:block> 
  </fo:block-container> 
</fo:table-cell>
```

Please help.

Comment: What XSL-FO processor do you use? If it is FOP, note that rounded corners is a **FOP extension**. This extension is only available in the development (trunk) version of FOP. See http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/extensions.html#rounded-corners and  http://wiki.apache.org/xmlgraphics-fop/RoundedBorders.

Comment: I am using FOP and I have tried the extensions in FOP given in the above link but that didn't work and it did not give rounded corners for tables. Is there any other options to get the rounded corners for tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Important**: to get rounded corners, you must use [**the trunk (development) version of FOP**](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk). It does not work with the latest released version (FOP 1.1). 
See also http://wiki.apache.org/xmlgraphics-fop/RoundedBorders.

FOP trunk can be obtained by checking out the code from the [Subversion repository](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xmlgraphics/fop/trunk/) and compiling as described [here](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/compiling.html).

There are also [nightly snapshots](http://ci.apache.org/projects/xmlgraphics/fop/snapshots/#installationg).

---

The main problem with the FO code in the question is that the names of the radius properties are wrong. See the specification at http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/extensions.html#rounded-corners. Also note that under Current Limitations, it says:

> Rounded corners on tables are not directly supported. To set rounded corners at the table level the table must have the `border-collapse` property set to `separate`.

---

It is not clear exactly what you want the output to look like, but with the following `fo:block` instead of the one in the question, you should see a noticeable difference:

```
<fo:block text-align="center" border-style="solid"
          fox:border-before-start-radius="7mm"
          fox:border-before-end-radius="7mm"> 
  <fo:inline font-family="RonBscRg" font-size="7pt">ee</fo:inline> 
</fo:block>
```

If you want all four corners rounded, simply use the shorthand `fox:border-radius`.

Comment: I have used the fox:border-radius for the table and not succeeded. Iam unable to post the code as its too long. Can you suggest me a way to post it.Thanks.

Comment: I tried to set the border-collapse  to separate along with the fox:border radius on the table and its still not working.

Comment: Please find the below link for a sample table that iam trying to get curved borders for.                           http://pastebin.com/FThhbQNG

Comment: The linked FO document works fine for me. I do get rounded corners. The only reason I can think of why it does not work for you is that you are not using the trunk version of fop after all. Please check this again.

Comment: Iam using the trunk version itself by including the http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/extensions link. Could you please tell me if there is some other link which I need to use.

Comment: I connected to the svn of the fop and built the built.xml using ant and used the fop jar obtained from it. It is  giving me compilation errors  with my java code to transform xml to pdf.I  am unable to figure out what to do next.

Comment: Have you tried to just run FOP from the command line? This question is about how to get rounded corners with FOP. I have already explained how to do that. Compilation errors in your Java code is a separate issue. If you need help with that, please ask a new question (and consider accepting this answer).

Comment: I didn't try to run it from command line. I used the fop jar obtained after compiling the fop  trunk version. When I used this jar by replacing the fop 1.1 jar I got compilation errors in my code which i used to transform xml to pdf.So I can't try to run the code and check if the svn version of fop is working.

Comment: FOP 2.0 was released in June 2015, with support for rounded corners. See http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.0/extensions.html#rounded-corners.